# Domain-specific word similarity

Tags: nlp, word2vec, similarity, cosine-similarity

Does anyone know how of an accurate tool or method that can be used to compute word embeddings or find similarity among domain-specific words? I'm working on an NLP project that involves computing cosine similarity between technical terms, such as "address" and "socket", but pre-trained models like word2vec aren't giving useful embeddings or accurate cosine similarities because they aren't specific to technical terms. Since the more general-nontechnical meanings of "address" and "socket" aren't similar to one another, these pretrained models aren't giving them sufficiently high similarity scores for the purposes of my project. Would appreciate any advice people would be able to offer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sufficient data from your specific domain, you can train your own word2vec model - whose resulting word-vectors, being only influenced by your domain data, will be far more reflective of the in-domain meanings.

Similarly, if you have a mixture of data where you have hints that *some* word uses are for different senses of a polysemous word, you could try preprocessing your text, using those hints, replacing the ambiguous tokens (like say `'address'`) with a larger number of distinct tokens (like `'address*networking'`, `'address*delivery'`, etc). Even with a lot of error in such a process, its results might be sufficient for a specific purpose.

For example, maybe you'd assume all docs of a certain type – like articles from a particular publication – always mean `'address*networking'` when they write `'address'`. That crude replacement, on just some subset of docs sufficient to collect enough varied examples of `'address*networking'` usage, might leave you with a good-enough word-vector for `'address*networking'`.

(More generally, deciding which word sense of multiple candidates is meant by a particular word is called "word sense disambiguation", and it might be possible to use other preexisting code for performing that to help preprocess texts - replacing ambiguous tokens with more-speciific stand-ins – before performing word2vec training.)

Even without such assistive pre-processing, there've been a number of research attempts to extend word2vec to better model words with multiple contrasting meanings. Googling for `[word2vec polysemy]` or `[polysemous embeddings]` should turn up a bunch of examples.

But I don't know any of those techniques that have become widely-used, or that are explicitly supported by major word2vec libraries, so I can't specifically recommend or show working code for any. I don't know a standard best-practice or off-the-shelf solution – you'd have to treat adopting those ideas from research papers as an R&D project, performing a lot of your own implementation/evaluation to see if any help with your goals.

Comment: This is useful advice, thank you!